# Using VBA to retrieve Column Headers from Excel files

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with someone who has  to identify certain variables within excel files. Currently, the man I'm working with has a great deal of folders and sub-folders that have Excel documents in them. He's using a VBA code that looks within a folder for a sub-folder, and then returns the pathway, then creating a hyperlink to the sub-folder (this isn't part of the VBA code below) and looking at all excel files within, no matter the level of sub-folders within the main folder.

Here's the code:

```
    Sub GetFolders()
Dim path As String
Dim folder As String
Dim row As Integer


path = "your directory here"
folder = Dir(path, vbDirectory)
row = 1

Do While folder <> ""
If (GetAttr(path & folder) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
    Cells(row, 1) = path & folder
    row = row + 1
End If
folder = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

This is great, but I know there has to be a better way. How can I manipulate this code to return COLUMN HEADERS of any excel files found A) within a folder or B) within a subfolder contained within a folder. I want these to be returned to an excel spreadsheet so that 100's of excel documents don't need to be opened, but rather just this one, and then we can identify any excel spreadsheets that need further investigation and ignore the rest.

Comment: It's relatively straightforward to expand the loop you have and open each workbook found. The decisions you have to make are a) where are the column headers in that workbook - only one sheet, multiple sheets, all sheets?; b) what row are the headers located on each of these sheets - row 1 or other rows? It's certainly possible... search around for these ideas and put together some code, then come back and ask some questions about what you've done.

Comment: It kinda sounds like you might be better off turning this into an Access DB.  This isn't the type of thing Excel's really built for.  That said, finding out why you have to go through all that to retrieve those specific headers might help us you find a better solution.  For example: If the columns are not the same from file to file, is there a pattern that could be found from the folder location?  Can the columns be standardized and left blank in some files?

Comment: With Excel 2010 or above you can use `Power Query` to query the column headers of excel files in folders without opening them

Comment: @slai - You can do the same thing in any version of Excel via ADO: `Recordset.Fields(foo).Name`

Comment: @Comintern You'll get only the field names if you issue a `Select`. And what is the `Select` you want to use? Maybe something like `Select * From [SheetWhichHopefullyExists$]` ? And what about any other sheet in the Excel file? I am unaware of any `Select` which allows you to inquire about all the *tables* or *sheets* in an Excel file (something like `sys.tables` on SQL Server). But I'd be happy to learn that I am mistaken.

Comment: @Ralph - If you don't know the sheet names, you can get them with `ADODB.Connection.OpenSchema` (column names too).

Comment: @Comintern I definitely learned something new and very useful today. Thanks for posting a complete answer with code. I'll certainly bookmark this one! *(+1)* from my side! Awesome stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can query them with ADO (adjust the connection string as needed):

```
'Requires reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects #.# Library
Private Function GetHeaders(filepath As String) As String()
    Dim output() As String
    Dim ado As New ADODB.Connection
    output = Split(vbNullString)

    With ado
        .Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & filepath & "';" & _
              "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";"
        With .OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)
            Dim table As String
            Dim columns As ADODB.Recordset
            Do While Not .EOF
                table = .Fields("TABLE_NAME")
                Set columns = ado.OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns, Array(Empty, Empty, table))
                With columns
                    Do While Not .EOF
                        ReDim Preserve output(UBound(output) + 1)
                        output(UBound(output)) = table & .Fields("COLUMN_NAME")
                        .MoveNext
                    Loop
                End With
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End With
    End With
    GetHeaders = output
End Function
```

Then call it like this for each file that you find:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim headers() As String
    Dim i As Long
    headers = GetHeaders("C:\Foo\Bar.xlsx")
    For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        Debug.Print headers(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note that this assumes you don't know the sheet names and need to get headers for ***all*** of them.  The strings in the output array will be in the form of `Sheet$Field`, but that can be adjusted according to need.

Answer (score 0):

Cell in col header is limited to 255 chars only due to limitation in ADODB.