# Loop to insert multiple values into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, vba

I am trying to insert a lot of values into SQL Server in one SQL insert statement. So for example..

```
Insert Into someDataBase
Values(value1, value2, value3,..., value120, value121)
```

All these values will be in the correct order on a sheet in Excel. I already created a loop to go through all the 121 values but I can't think of a loop for the inserting the values without writing each value individually.

Can anyone help me out?

My code looks like this:

```vb
Sub AddRows()
' In VBE you need to go Tools References and check Microsoft Active X Data Objects 2.x library

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Password As String
Dim SQLStr As String


Dim comm As ADODB.Command
Set comm = New ADODB.Command
Dim param As ADODB.Parameter
Dim getType As String

SQLStr = "Insert Into [DB] Values("
For i = 1 To 121
    'Get type
    getType = CellType(i, Cells(2, i))
    SQLStr = SQLStr & "?,"
    Set param = New ADODB.Parameter
    param.Name = "Param" & i
    Set param = comm.CreateParameter("param" & i, getType, adParamInput, 1000)
    param.Attributes = adParamNullable
    Debug.Print (param.Type)
    comm.Parameters.Append param
Next i
SQLStr = Left(SQLStr, Len(SQLStr) - 1) & ");"

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.CommandTimeout = 0
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

comm.ActiveConnection = Cn
comm.CommandText = SQLStr
comm.CommandType = adCmdText


Dim test As String
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'For x = 2 To lastrow
    For i = 1 To 121
        Debug.Print (Cells(2, i).Value)
        comm.Parameters.Item("Param" & i).Value = Cells(2, i).Value
    Next
    comm.Execute
'Next x

Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing
```

End Sub

This is a portion of my CellType Function:

```
Private Function CellType(Num) As MultipleValues
Application.Volatile
CellType.CellNum = 50
Select Case True
    Case Num = 1
        CellType.CellType = adInteger
    Case Num = 2
        CellType.CellType = adInteger
    Case Num = 3
        CellType.CellType = adVarWChar
        CellType.CellNum = 255
    Case Num = 4
        CellType.CellType = adCurrency
    Case Num = 5
        CellType.CellType = adVarWChar
        CellType.CellNum = 255
```

The values for the first 5 values are: 0,   null,   6071/1, 44.5,   Biltmore Fleur De Lis Collection Authentic Wrought Iron

It breaks on the second value which is a null but should be an integer.

Comment: If it's in excel, the work is done for you. Just format it in excel and copy/paste it into ssms.

Comment: By values, do you mean records or fields?

Comment: @Comintern I guess i mean fields. I would be inserting each individual cell as a value.

Comment: @dfundako I know that I can just copy and paste that, However this is going to be part of a program that runs whenever someone wants to update a table. So this would be automating that process,

Comment: This is actually fairly easy if you parameterize your query - can you edit your code into the question?

Comment: @SteveG Probably would be easiest through a SSIS package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would generally agree that using an SSIS package would be the best way to approach this, but if you want to do it through code, it's not difficult with a parameterized query in ADODB:

Use the `?` placeholder for parameters when you're building your INSERT statement, and add parameters to an `ADODB.Command` object:

```vb
Dim comm As ADODB.Command
Set comm = New ADODB.Command
Dim param As ADODB.Parameter

SQLStr = "Insert Into [db] Values("
For i = 1 To 121
    SQLStr = SQLStr & "?,"
    Set param = New ADODB.Parameter
    param.Name = "Param" & i
    comm.Parameters.Append param
Next i
SQLStr = Left(SQLStr, Len(SQLStr) - 1) & ");"
```

When you're done, you'll have a matched set of parameters and placeholders.
Then open your connection (or do it before this, it really doesn't make much difference) and set up the command:

```vb
comm.ActiveConnection = Cn
comm.CommandText = SQLStr
comm.CommandType = adCmdText
```

Finally, loop through your rows for each record, loop through the values and assign them to parameters, and execute for each row:

```vb
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For x = 2 To lastrow
    For i = 1 To 121
        comm.Parameters.Item("Param" & i).Value = Cells(x, i).Value
    Next
    comm.Execute
Next x
```

Note that ADODB Commands are optimized to be looped over - the backend treats this more like a batch insert, so there isn't really much point in trying to build a gigantic insert will all the records in it at once.

Comment: This seems to make things a lot easier and i will have to try to use this method in other projects I have worked on. However I am getting an error.

Comment: The error says: Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.

Comment: @SteveG - I'm not surprised at all, this isn't really complete code (just an illustration of the concept) - you also need to supply the parameter type and the specify that it's an input value.  See [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3578/working-with-ado/12354/creating-parameterized-commands) for a more detailed sample of how to build a parameter.

Comment: For param1 - param121 would I need to create parameters for each one?

Comment: @SteveG - Yep. I usually automate building insert commands by reading the table schema and using that to build both the sql and parameters.  There's an [example of reading the schema here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39135358/4088852).

Comment: Okay perfect that makes things way easier. Thanks again!

Comment: Hello again, How would you handle NULL values in a numeric field? I know that SQL Server would accept it however the Createparameters method does not allow it.

Comment: @SteveG - It's been a while since I inserted nulls, but IIR you have to set the parameter `.Attributes` to `adParamNullable`.

Comment: @SteveG - If you're building parameters using `OpenSchema` the field to check for that attribute is `.Fields("IS_NULLABLE")`.

Comment: I updated my code because I believe I am doing it correctly after doing some research. But I am still getting the error thrown.

Comment: @SteveG - Ah, I thought you were using `OpenSchema` to get parameter information.  `getType` needs to be the *database* type, not the cell type - it's also an enum, not a string. You can get all of this information by just [querying the schema](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39135358/4088852).

Comment: What do you mean when you say enum? I created a method getType which gives a type like this: adInteger , based on what the type in the db is.

Comment: I was also having a lot of trouble trying to query the schema so I just worked around it. I'm not the best programmer so my getType method is very impractical but it is just hard-coding the type based on the type in the db.

Comment: @SteveG - I'm guessing the `Size` parameter is where you're hitting issues. Unless everything is `VARCHAR(1000)`, it has to match the database field size if you specify it. Whether or not it's *required* is dependent on the driver you're using and the backend.

Comment: I fixed that part of the code making sure to have the correct size parameter. However I still get an error thrown saying: "Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation." It throws it on a Null value.

Comment: It seems to throw it on items that have are supposed to have a integer value but instead have a null. Is it possible that I am not changing the attribute to allow null values correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if the excel spreadsheet has special formatting, but if its in a CSV format, you can use SQL Server Import and Export Wizard to do this. Here's how:

1. In SQL Server Management Studio, login to your database server.
2. Right click the database you want to import data into and select **Task -> Import Data**
   [Import Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3q5X.png)
3. On the *Choose Data Source* screen, choose Microsoft Excel from the *Data Source* drop down. Enter the file path to the excel spreadsheet in *Excel file path*. Select the appropriate Excel version in *Excel version*. If the first row in the spreadsheet contains the database column names, check the *First row has column names*. If it's just data, uncheck it.
   [Choose Data Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qpn0.png)
4. Click **Next** and choose **Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server** in the *Destination* drop down. Select your sql server name in *Server name* drop down. Choose *Authentication* option. Click **Refresh**, then choose the database you want to insert the Excel data into.
5. On the *Specify Table Copy or Query* window, select **Copy data from one or more table or views**. Click **Next**.
6. Select the check box next to **Sheet1$** in the *Source* column. Click in the *Destination* column and select the table you want to import the Excel data into. Clicking the **Preview** button will show the query and how the data will look in the new table. Click **Next**.
7. The mapping should be good on the *Review Data Type Mapping* page. This window allows you to setup options on what SQL should do in regards to converting. Defaults should be fine. Click **Next**.
8. Click **Next**. The import should run immediately.
9. Review the summary page and click **Finish**.
10. The import will perform several operations. Green check marks indicate that the operation was successful. Read circles with X's indicate failure. If you get a failure, post an image of it here with your data and the hyperlinked message from the *Message* column.

If you want, you can check out the **bulk insert** command as well on MSDN. I don't have enough rep to post more images. I'll finish it later when I have enough.

Comment: Well, now that you've posted VBA code, this is mostly meaningless. I would suggest doing a parameterized query or concatenating the cells as strings in each row of the spreadsheet, adding comma delimiters between each cell read, and placing each row into an array.

Comment: I would then iterate through the string array and execute the INSERT INTO statement for each string in the array. However, be mindful that this can lead you open to SQL injection if the dynamic query isn't parameterized.