# Read or Fetch all the column headers in a excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I wanted to just read all the column headers of my excel sheet.

> public class Reader_2 {
>         public static final String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "C:/Users/kqxk171/Documents/Records Management
>   Application/9.2_initial_test_report.xlsx";

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));
    System.out.println("Workbook has " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheets : ");

    Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.sheetIterator();

    System.out.println("Retrieving Sheets using Iterator");
    while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {
        Sheet sheet = sheetIterator.next();
        System.out.println("=> " + sheet.getSheetName());
    }
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();


    for (Row row: sheet) {
        for(Cell cell: row) 
        {
            row.getRowNum();
            String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);

            System.out.print(cellValue + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }





}
```

}

Comment: this would help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39132792/using-vba-to-retrieve-column-headers-from-excel-files

Comment: Hey, Thanks but i need to run this for around 6 million excel file. can VBA achieve this ? if yes then could you please share me the code

Comment: Also please share me the java code as well.