# VBA Add row to csv file

Tags: excel, vba, csv, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have searched a lot but most of results were related to excel. So I could not find any clue to my answer.

I am trying to this by ms access2010:

I have several csv files with headers on the first row. all fields are delimited by , and they are all string(double quoted, they have many , in the double quotation).

I don't know how many columns are there in each of csv file.
I want to insert new row between first row(header) and second row.

How can I find out how many columns csv file has?
And how can I append new text line on the second row?

Comment: You can open a CSV file in Excel, add the line, and save it back in CSV format.

Comment: CSV is a text format. You don't even need to open it in Excel - just use the VBA text file handling functions or a `FileSystemObject`. If you don't know the column layout, the other alternative is to connect to it with an ADODB text driver, [read the schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39135358/4088852), and just add a row via an `INSERT` command.

Comment: I am asking it how to do it with vba. Everyone knows how to open it and add new row.
Please don't relate csv file with something else. All I can use is ms access, all I have is just given csv files.

Comment: I want to know how to build a function(csv file as parameter) that get number of headers of csv file and a function(csv file, number of headers, array value for the fields as parameter) that add new row

Comment: Read the linked answer in my comment above. It shows you ***exactly*** how to read the headers - you just need to connect to it with [a csv driver](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-text-odbc-driver/) instead of an Excel one. Adding a row is a simple insert statement, as noted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *FileSystemObject* is an excellent tool for such tasks:

```
Public Function InsertLine()

    Const TmpExtension      As String = ".tmp"
    Const BakExtension      As String = ".bak"

    Dim FileSystemObject    As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim SourceStream        As Scripting.TextStream
    Dim TargetStream        As Scripting.TextStream

    Dim Fields              As Variant
    Dim Values              As Variant
    Dim FieldCount          As Long
    Dim Item                As Long
    Dim Field               As String
    Dim FileName            As String
    Dim BaseName            As String
    Dim TempFileName        As String
    Dim Path                As String
    Dim Extension           As String
    Dim DotExtension        As String
    Dim TextLine            As String

    Set FileSystemObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    ' File to modify.
    FileName = "c:\test\timezone.csv"

    BaseName = FileSystemObject.GetBaseName(FileName)
    Extension = FileSystemObject.GetExtensionName(FileName)
    Path = FileSystemObject.GetParentFolderName(FileName)
    DotExtension = "." & Extension
    TempFileName = BaseName & TmpExtension

    Set SourceStream = FileSystemObject.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)
    Set TargetStream = FileSystemObject.CreateTextFile(TempFileName, ForWriting)

    ' Read header line.
    TextLine = SourceStream.ReadLine
    ' Copy header line.
    TargetStream.WriteLine TextLine

    ' Create line two.
    Fields = Split(TextLine, ",")
    ' FYI.
    FieldCount = UBound(Fields)
    ' Array to hold values.
    Values = Fields
    For Item = LBound(Fields) To UBound(Fields)
        Select Case Item
            Case 0
                Field = "SomeValue"
            Case 1
                Field = "OtherValue"
            Case 2
                Field = "YetAValue"
            ' etc.
            Case Else
                Field = CStr(Item)
        End Select
        Values(Item) = Chr(34) & Field & Chr(34)
    Next
    ' Write line two.
    TargetStream.WriteLine Join(Values, ",")

    ' Copy remaining lines.
    While Not SourceStream.AtEndOfStream
        TargetStream.WriteLine SourceStream.ReadLine
    Wend
    ' Close files.
    SourceStream.Close
    TargetStream.Close

    ' Rename files.
    FileSystemObject.MoveFile FileName, FileSystemObject.BuildPath(Path, BaseName & BakExtension)
    FileSystemObject.MoveFile TempFileName, FileSystemObject.BuildPath(Path, BaseName & DotExtension)

End Function
```

Requires a Reference set to: *Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime*

Comment: in my case, renaming is making error because Path is including file name. Thank you

Comment: You are right. Somehow my last correction went South. See corrected code, please.

Answer (score -3):

Just record a Macro to do the work for you.  I did that, and I got this code, below.

```
Sub Makro1()

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Coding\R Programming\Merge Multiple CSV Files\CSV5.csv", Local:=True

Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "field1"
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "field2"
Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "field3"
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```